# Pandas add a new column with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
ID PRICE SALES COST
1   10     10   5
2   10      5   3
3   10      5
4   10     
5   10      4   2
```

Expected output:
I want to add a new column and it is calculated like this:
PRICE / (SALES - COST)
How to deal with the situation when (SALES - COST) is 0? I want to leave it as blank.

```
ID  PRICE  SALES COST  P/E
1   10     10    5     2
2   10      5    3     5
3   10      5          2
4   10     
5   10      4    2     5
```

Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this in two steps, first, `fillna` with `0`, and then divide:

```
t = df.fillna(0)
s = t.SALES - t.COST

df.assign(PE=t.PRICE.div(s).where(s.ne(0)))
```

```
   ID  PRICE  SALES  COST   PE
0   1     10   10.0   5.0  2.0
1   2     10    5.0   3.0  5.0
2   3     10    5.0   NaN  2.0
3   4     10    NaN   NaN  NaN
4   5     10    4.0   2.0  5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but another way could be:

```
df['gross'] = df['SALES'].fillna(0) - df['COST'].fillna(0)
```

Then

```
df.loc[df['gross'] != 0, 'P/E'] = df['Price'] / df['gross']
```

One-line version of the above might be:

```
df.loc[(df['SALES'].fillna(0) - df['COST'].fillna(0)) != 0, 'P/E'] = df['Price'] / df['gross']
```